# How to populate grails gsp select(drop down box) field?

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, gsp

So, the controller returns a list of Race object/models to the view.

```
def addquestion(Long id){

    def event = CompositeEvent.get(id)

    [races: event.races]

}
```

The only thing worth noting is that these Race models have a property "name". So, i want to populate the select drop down box with the names of the races but i am having hard time following the documentation so i came here to get some help from experts. Here is what i did but i dont get the names populated but types.

```
<g:select name="asd" from="${races}" value="1" optionKey="name" />
```

My understanding was that the from attribute is where i should point to the model or list which in my case is "races" since this was the list of Race objects passed down to the view and optionKey is the property that points to the property of that object to print. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html) `g:select` has the two properties `optionKey` and `optionValue`, that results into the following html:

```
<select name="{selectName}">
  <option value="{optionKey}">{optionValue}</option>
  <option value="{optionKey}">{optionValue}</option>
  <option value="{optionKey}">{optionValue}</option>
</select>
```

> i dont get the names populated but types

because you don't set the `optionValue`, the default `toString()` representation occurs, which seems to be what you call "types". The following code should do what you want it to do:

```
<g:select name="races" from="${races}" value="1" optionKey="id" optionValue="name" />
```